# When import a theme into Google Presentation, the original fonts reset

Tags: google-drive-api

Well, presentation theme can be successfully imported but the original fonts from the theme is all reset to Arial. Is there way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Customize titles, subtitles, headings and text style**

With styles, you can quickly customize the look of text in a Google document. Use the new styles toolbar menu to format text in your document.

- Highlight a selection of text with the font size and style that you'd
  like to use for normal text or a particular heading.
- Go to the styles toolbar menu, and click the arrow next to Normal
  text or Heading 1-6.
- Select Update Heading X to match selection.
- All of the text in your document with the same text type, such as
  Heading 4 or Normal text, will be updated to match the font and font
  size of your initial selection.

**Save default styles for your docum**ents

You can save customized styles to be used by default for new documents.

- Expand the styles drop-down menu.
- Point your mouse to Options.
- Select Save as my default styles.

Then, apply that style to a new document:

- Expand the styles drop-down menu.
- Point your mouse to Options.
- Select Use my default styles.

To restore your default styles to the default Google document styles:

- Follow Steps 1 and 2 above.
- Select Reset styles.

Comment: sorry, it doesn't seem what i wanted?